# Can no longer publish content types from hub in o365

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type, content-type-hub

I was working with content types yesterday in the content type hub. I was able to publish items. This morning I can't publish things anymore. I get the following error:

> Sorry, something went wrong
>
> The operation failed on one or more Metadata web service application
>   proxies:  Taxonomy_+q13bKzN06taIYblFDpgvQ==. Please contact your
>   administrator and check the log files for more error details.

This same error occurs whether I am trying to publish a new content type, or if I am trying to republish an existing content type.  I haven't changed anything since I published content types yesterday.  I tried re-publishing content types in a completely different group and got the same message.

When I looked at the error logs, I noticed the Content Type Subscriber Site field is blank and it seems to be required.  I'm not sure if this is an indication of what is wrong, and if so, what I need to do.

Answer (score 3):

You are not alone, I have the same issue on my tenant right now.

I raised a ticket to Microsoft and spoke to them - as of today (7-April-2017), this is an issue in their production system at the moment and is effectively a Service Outage. They are working on identifying the root cause and fix, but could take some time... Given the severity of the issue, I would hope this would be fixed in 24-48 hours, but this is purely a guess.

I will post back here once I have an update from Microsoft.

Answer (score 2):

We can't help you as this is SharePoint Online and a service-related issue. Open a ticket with Microsoft via the Office 365 Admin portal.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem yesterday and this morning.  I tried again this afternoon and 2 Content Types Published OK.  Then I got the error again on the 3rd and 4th etc...

This from the Office 365 Admin's Advisory Panel

SP98120 - Content type publishing issue

Updated: 2017-04-07 21:51 (UTC)
Start time: 2017-04-05 19:14 (UTC)
Status: Restoring service

User impact: Users are receiving errors when publishing new site content types from the SharePoint Online content type hub.

Latest message:

Title: Content type publishing issue

User Impact: Users are receiving errors when publishing new site content types from the SharePoint Online content type hub.

More info: The error received says: "The operation failed on one or more Metadata web service application proxies: Taxonomy_masR1gLITCWWPDUbODEIOA==. Please contact your administrator and check the log files for more error details...
Correlation ID: 2d75e59d-90d6-3000-f0d6-00d2f9b3649e"

Current status: We've confirmed our suspicion that the cause of impact is a permissions configuration issue. We're not certain how this issue was introduced, but we're working to develop and test a fix that should resolve the underlying cause. We expect the fix to be ready for deployment within the next 2-3 days. In parallel, we're continuing to investigate how this issue was introduced.

Scope of impact: A few customers have reported this issue, and our analysis indicates that this issue may potentially affect any of your users attempting to publish new content types.

Start time: Wednesday, April 5, 2017, at 7:14 PM UTC

Preliminary root cause: A critical file within the systems that facilitate publishing of site content types was inaccessible due to mis-configured permissions settings. This resulted in intermittent errors when users attempt to publish new site content types.

Next update by: Monday, April 10, 2017, at 6:00 PM UTC

Comment: all resolved... 
'Preliminary root cause: A critical file within the systems that facilitate publishing of site content types was inaccessible due to misconfigured permissions settings. This resulted in intermittent errors when users attempted to publish new site content types.

Next steps:
- We're reviewing our deployment and maintenance procedures related to file system permissions to find ways to prevent this problem from happening again.

This is the final update for the event.'

Answer (score 0):

Just saw this update, hope this helps you out..

Title: Content type publishing issue

User Impact: Users are receiving errors when publishing new site content types from the SharePoint Online content type hub.

More info: The error received says: "The operation failed on one or more Metadata web service application proxies: Taxonomy_masR1gLITCWWPDUbODEIOA==. Please contact your administrator and check the log files for more error details...
Correlation ID: 2d75e59d-90d6-3000-f0d6-00d2f9b3649e"

Current status: We've completed the process of developing the fix, and we're building the software that includes the fix for further testing and deployment. Following extensive testing, we expect the deployment to begin within the next two days. Once the deployment begins, it should complete within three to five days.

Scope of impact: A few customers have reported this issue, and our analysis indicates that this issue may potentially affect any of your users attempting to publish new content types.

Start time: Wednesday, April 5, 2017, at 7:14 PM UTC

Preliminary root cause: A critical file within the systems that facilitate publishing of site content types was inaccessible due to misconfigured permissions settings. This resulted in intermittent errors when users attempt to publish new site content types.

Next update by: Wednesday, April 12, 2017, at 6:00 PM UTC